# Is $eSe \cong S^1$ possible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

Let $S$ be a semigroup. Denote $S^1 := S\sqcup \{1\}$ (adding external identity) - so $1x=x=x1$ for every $x\in S$. In present case we add the external identity whether or not $S$ is a monoid.

For finite semigroups it is oviously impossible that $S$ contains an isomorphic copy of $S^1$. Is it possible that for some semigroup $S$, there exists a subsemigroup $R\subseteq S$ such that $R\cong S^1$ (as monoids)? Of course, this requires that $S$ contains an idempotent. We can make it a bit more precise.

**Question**. Does there exist a semigroup $S$ such that $eSe \cong S^1$ for some idempotent $e\in S$? (May assume $S=SeS$ if necessary)

I suspect the answer is no. Motivating example - suppose we have a semigroup with one idempotent, like $S:=(\mathbb N, \cdot)$. It is impossible that $S^1\cong R\leqslant S$ because $S^1$ contains two idempotents. So as long as there are finitely many idempotents in $S$, the answer is no, because $S^1$ would contain one idempotent too many.

For infinitely many idempotents, one can consider (rectangular) bands, for instance. A recipe for cooking any rectangular band is definining $(a,b)(a',b') := (a,b')$ on $A\times B$. But then $eSe = \{e\}$ so these won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $S=(\{1,2,3,\cdots\},\mathrm{max})$. Every positive integer $e$ is idempotent and is an identity with respect to the upper set $\{e,e+1,e+2,\cdots\}$. We can say $eSe=S$ for $e=1$.

Then $S^1\cong(\{0,1\cdots,\},\mathrm{max})$ with $0$ the external identity, and $S^1\cong S$ via $n\mapsto n+1$.

Comment: Aha, how clever!